# OpenID Connect lightweight library

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, openid, openid-connect

I'm looking for OpenID Connect (OIDC) Relying Party **lightweight library** that will have these routines implemented.

1. Compose "Authentication Request"
2. Validate "id_token" signature
       (including downloading certificate from metadata endpoint)
3. Parse "id_token" JWT

The only OIDC flow to be supported is so called "**implicit flow**" where server answers with "id_token" (and "access_token" if requested) right from authorization endpoint ([spec link](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowSteps)).

Searching over NuGet repository seems to yield the only suitable option - OWIN middleware, and even though I can confirm it works, it would be better to have lightweight alternative.

[image: OIDC implicit flow]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just sharing what worked for me.

To get 1st goal accomplished NuGet package called `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client` ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client/)) can be used (package from IdentityServer creators that is incredible itself). An example that shows basic usage is below.

```
var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(AuthorizeEndpointUrl));

string url = client.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
    clientId: ClientId,
    redirectUri: RedirectUri,
    responseType: "id_token",
    responseMode: "form_post",
    nonce: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    additionalValues: additionalValues);
```

As to parsing and validation of the JWT received from OIDC Identity Provider the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)) Microsoft's NuGet package is a way to go. The code snippet is bellow as well.

```
var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    IssuerSigningTokens = GetSigningTokens(MetadataEndpointUrl),
    ValidAudience = ValidAudience,
    ValidIssuer = ValidIssuer,
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

SecurityToken validated;
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, parameters, out validated);

return validated as JwtSecurityToken;
```

This all lightweight and keeps your application clean from unnecessary dependencies.

[image: NuGets]