# WSO2 Implicit Flow not returning id_token

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to authenticate a user from a custom web app with an OpenID Connect Service Provider within WSO2. I am following an answer on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255401/openid-connect-lightweight-library) and added the Nuget package Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client. My code is very similar to the linked article:

```
 var client = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(serviceProviderAuthorizeUrl));

        var url = client.CreateImplicitFlowUrl(
            clientId,
            redirectUri: redirectUrl,
            scope: scope,
            nonce: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        Response.Redirect(url);
```

The url comes out to be: `https://{wso2_url}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={my_client_id}&response_type=token&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F{mydomain}%2F{my_app}%2FCallback.aspx&nonce=f0db4eac-18df-46f6-92f1-c28ba621596d`

Now this does work and returns an access_token: `https://{my_domain}/{my_app}/Callback.aspx#token_type=Bearer&expires_in=970&access_token=067e3366217798986912326a86abd92f`

My issue is that I have no idea who the user is. Further more, this [WSO2 article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Implicit+Client+Profile+with+Playground) shows that if I pass a response_type:id_token I should be able to decode the response and find out who the user is by using the "sub" attribute but I am not getting the id_token response. The code above creates a url with a response_type of token instead. Simply changing the response_type gives me an error. How can I use implicit flow in WSO2 and get the id_token response?

I followed this [article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On) for the configuration of WSO2. I currently have Implicit and Client Credential checked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these as query parameters.

```
response_type=id_token
client_id=xxxxx
redirect_uri=http://xx.com/xx/x
nonce=xxxx
scope=openid
```

Comment: The CreateImplicitFlowUrl does not take in a parameter for response_type. I have also tried this: `var url = serviceProviderAuthorizeUrl + "?response_type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(responseType) + "&client_id" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId) +
                      "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectUrl) + "&nonce=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) + "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scope);
            Response.Redirect(url);` and passed id_token as response_type and I received an error from WSO2. I wish it were that simple but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you pass on the scope intended to use  for the Idp (WSO2) to know what data it needs to return. Make sure your scop
scope=openid.